# PHP getting selected table rows from checkboxes

Tags: php, checkbox, html-table

I have a PHP form where a table is created of all files in a folder on the server, and each row created is assigned a checkbox which will be used to decide which files are to be deleted or shared etc. Each row is given a name `checkbox[$rownumber]` to distinguish each, and then when a button is clicked, for the moment to ensure I can get it working, it just prints the rows that are selected - but I can't get this working.

Initially, as rows are created in the table from the server, this is the code, which correctly creates them as I wish

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['deleteFile']))  
{var_dump($_REQUEST);
    if(isset($_POST['checkbox']))
    {

        print_r($_POST);
    }
}
?>

<form name="mainHomescreen" action="MainHomescreen.php" method="POST">
<nav>
    <input type="text" name="Search" value="Search" style = "color:#888;" onFocus="inputFocus(this)" onBlur="inputBlur(this)"/>
</nav>

<sidebar>
<input type="button" value="Create Folder" onClick="createFolder()"/>
<input type="button" value="Download Selected Files/Folders" onClick=" "/>
<input type="button" value="Encrypt Selected" onClick="encrypt()"/><br>
<input type="button" value="Share Selected" onClick="shareFolder()"/>

<!-- upload a file -->
<div id="fileUpload">
    <div id="uploadPopup">
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="uploadForm" method="post" name="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        Select file to upload: <input name="fileUpload" type="file" /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submitFile"/>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="button" name="upload" value="Upload File" onClick="showUpload()"/>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="deleteFile"/>
<input type="button" value="Rename" onClick=" "/><br>
<input type="button" value="Password Protect Folder/ File" onClick=" "/><br><br>
</sidebar>
<article>
<span class="error"><?php echo $error;?></span>
<table id="detailView" style="width:100%">
<!-- php to create table -->
<?php
//open file names
$dir = opendir("/home/a1962403/public_html/files");

$filearray = array(array(array()));

echo '<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%">';
echo '
<tr>
    <th> </th>
    <th>File</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Size</th>
</tr>
';

$rownumber = 0;

  //List files in directory
  while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false)
   {
    //gets the file date, string needed decoding otherwise throws error.

    $date = @filemtime($file);
    $date = date("F d Y H:i:s.", filemtime(utf8_decode("/home/a1962403/public_html/files/$file")));

    $size = filesize("/home/a1962403/public_html/files/$file") . ' bytes';

    $rownumber = $rownumber + 1;

    //prints a table row
    echo '<tr class="bottomline">';
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[$rownumber]' value='[$rownumber]' </td>";
    echo "<td>$file</td>";
    echo "<td>$date</td>";
    echo "<td>$size</td>";
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
closedir($dir);
?>
</article>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

From this, I have a submit button called 'deleteFile', which I am wanting to use to as I said for the moment, just get what is selected to ensure it works, but it's not actually giving me any output so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($_REQUEST)` right after the `isset()` check?

Comment: After if(isset_REQUEST['deleteFile'])) it's array(4) { ["Search"]=> string(6) "Search" ["fileUpload"]=> string(0) "" ["deleteFile"]=> string(6) "Delete" ["siteowner"]=> string(1) "1" }

Comment: Can you show more of your code? The complete `form`.

Comment: Added more code above @RST

Comment: how about the COMPLETE `form`. And on a side note are you aware you are using two `table` tags? Is that intentionally?

Comment: Added full form code

Comment: just noticed you have nested `form`s I don't think that is going to result in a stable situation.

Comment: Putting the pop up form outside the main form still works like it did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your row formatting may be the problem

`echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[$rownumber]' value='[$rownumber]' </td>";`

Change it to:

```
   echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[" . $rownumber . "]' value='". $rownumber . "' </td>";
```

And because your are numbering from 0 up you could also just use `checkbox[]` as a name.

It would help to this form live.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks. Had no idea you could make $_REQUEST values an array. Cool

Answer (score 0):

You are right to use `isset` when determining whether a checkbox is checked or not, but you are using differring names:

```
isset($_POST['checkbox'])
```

will return true if

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
```

is checked.

You have to refer to posted inputs using their names in the `$_POST` array.

---

In this case, you need to check for `checkbox[$rownumber]`, which, as is seemingly trivial, requires you to know the row numbers when posting:

**PHP code**

```
if (isset($_POST["checkbox[$rownumber]"]))
{
    // This checkbox is checked
}
```

If you don't know the exact input names, you might want to iterate through the `$_POST` array:

**PHP code**

```
foreach ($_POST as $input_name => $input_value)
{
    if (strpos($input_name, 'checkbox') !== false)
    {
        // This input's name contains the substring 'checkbox'
    }
}
```

Note the type-strict comparison at strpos.

Comment: There is nothing in `$_REQUEST` to refer to, yet.

Comment: I see, although the name difference issues would have also appeared after that. Let me have a look.