# how to get the value of the checked row

Tags: php, loops, checkbox

I need to get the value of the selected option if the checkbox is checked. For example, I checked the checkbox in the third row. In another page I want to get the value of the third row selected option. Please don't use the `$a` to get the data.

```
<form method = "post" action = "">
<table>
    <?php
        for($a = 0;$a <=3; $a++){
            echo '<tr><td>';
            echo '<input type = "checkbox" name = "chckbx">';
            echo '</td><td>';
            echo '<select name = "slct1">';
            echo '<option>';
            echo  $a;
            echo '</option>';
            echo '</select>';
            echo '</td></tr>';
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You're missing a form tag and there's no name on the element. You'll need both of those if you want PHP to have access to the selected value. Can you show your rendered HTML?

Comment: i edited my code . so how can i now get the value? sorry . im a new to this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343410/php-getting-selected-table-rows-from-checkboxes

this helped me. thanks a lot